# how to make object move in specific position flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I make an mc object. this object can move right and left with keyboard. details are when I push rightkey it moves to right position in certain coordinate and when I push leftkey it moves to left position in certain coordinate. I want the object just move in 3 position.

for this case, I tried to use array.

```
var P:Array = [new Point(100, 300), new Point(275, 300), new Point(425, 300)];
var M:Array = [Kotak];
```

but when I input them to my code, it doesn't work and no error appears. anyone can tell me where's my fault?

this's my full code :

```
import flash.geom.Point;

//gerak pemain
var pemainKanan:Boolean = false;
var pemainTengah:Boolean = false;
var pemainKiri:Boolean = false;

//kecepatan
var kecepatanPemain:int = 20;

        //Array object acak
    var P:Array = [new Point(100, 300), new Point(275, 300), new Point(425, 300)];
    var M:Array = [Kotak];
    //var P:Point = new Point(100, 300);


Kotak.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, k);
function k(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            pemainKanan = false;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            pemainKiri = false;
        }
}

Kotak.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kk);
function kk(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            pemainKanan = true;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            pemainKiri = true;
        }
}

Kotak.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eframe);
    function eframe(e:Event):void{
        if(pemainKanan == true){
            //pemain.gotoAndStop("right");
            Kotak.x = P[0];
        }
        else if(pemainKiri == true){
            //pemain.gotoAndStop("left");
            Kotak = P[1];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain that in detail? From what I've read I understand that you want a MovieClip to move to three positions. For example if it is on position0 and right is pressed it should move to position1, but if it's in position1 it should move to position2 and the other way around with left button. Is this what you want to do? If it is there is no need for the ENTER_FRAME event, since all it can be done maybe with an index.

```
Kotak.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kk);
var index:int=0;
function kk(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        if(index==0){
            Kotak.x = P[1];
        }
        else{
            if(index==1){
                Kotak.x = P[2];
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        if(index==2){
            Kotak.x = P[1];
        }
        else{
            if(index==1){
                Kotak.x = P[0];
            }
        }
        index--;
    }
}
```